# awaitReactions doesn't work properly discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to set `max` as 'infinite', I would like the user to be able to react more than once, I've tried setting this value to an highier than 1 but if i do that it doesn't work

```
  embedMessage
    .awaitReactions(
      (reaction, user) => emoji.includes(reaction.emoji.name),

      { max: 1, time: timeOut && 3600000 } //1h
    )
    .then((collected) => {
      console.log("test");
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      message.reply(e);
    });
```

Comment: `max` is optional. I'm pretty sure the default is infinite.

Comment: actually I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: it work just if I set max to 1

Comment: Also, what does "that doesn't work" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: the the console.log inside then it's never called

Comment: It might be because `time` accepts a number, not a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [djs guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents), you must set the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent flag, else discord does not send you the reaction events.

All the flags are defined [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).